# Influencing rendering order of HTML (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, rendering

I have a relatively simple site. Left hand side I have tree menu (Telerik component), and depending on the choice from the tree, I fill out the main body of the page with relatively static HTML content. Each click in the tree produces a full page update.

Since the use of the tree component, rendering became slow (~1sec). **The main problem is that the background of the main body div is loaded last emphesizing the slowness very drasticly.**

Is there a way to influence that the browser should render the background first, and e.g., the tree component last? That could improve the perception of loading time radically while actually not change the real loading time at all.

Btw, in IE9 rendering speed is fantastic, in Firefox and Chrome, it is around 1 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the speed problem was caused by a caching "issue" and appears only under Cassini in debug mode. As soon as deploying on IIS, the problem disappears.